# Is it possible to do a poisson distribution with the probabilities based on integers?

Tags: probability, ethereum, solidity, poisson

Working within Solidity and the Ethereum EVM and Decimals don't exist. Is there a way I could mathematically still create a Poisson distribution using integers ?  it doesnt have to be perfect, i.e rounding or losing some digits may be acceptable.

Comment: The Poisson distribution is a counting distribution, it's already based on integers.

Comment: Thanks yes this is true for number of occurrences , but the probabilitiy calculations are all decimals. I ended up finding what I think is a reasonable solution in the results anyways, not sure if the math is really correct lol

Comment: Given that a) probabilities are numbers between 0 and 1, and b) the probabilities for  a Poisson involve `exp(-lambda)` and e is not a rational number, you're going to get decimals.

Comment: and back to the beginning we go, Is it possible to represent this type of distribution with rational numbers accepting that some accuracy or significance in digits will be lost ?

Comment: Floating point numbers have finite precision anyway, so in principle you can always express them as rationals.  For instance, Ruby claims that `Math::E.to_r => (6121026514868073/2251799813685248)`, and you could do similar conversions for the `lambda**x` portion of the calculation.  A decent rational library could then reduce the results using GCD calculations.  You're on your own as to whether Ethereum can do any of that, though.

Comment: Cheers, this is getting to the limit of my understanding.. But definitely sounds like something that will work, I did something along the lines of ensuring the numerator was always larger and dropping any remainders, I have my distribution between 0 - 10,000. Its not a super smooth transition, but I think will suit my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Let me preface by stating that what follows is not going to be (directly) helpful to you with etherium/solidity. However, it produces probability tables that you might be able to use for your work.

I ended up intrigued by the question of how accurate you could be in expressing the Poisson probabilities as rationals, so I put together the following script in Ruby to try things out:

```rb
def rational_poisson(lmbda)
  Hash.new.tap do |h|   # create a hash and pass it to this block as 'h'.
    # Make all components of the calculations rational to allow
    # cancellations to occur wherever possible when dividing
    e_to_minus_lambda = Math.exp(-lmbda).to_r
    factorial = 1r
    lmbda = lmbda.to_r
    power = 1r
    (0...).each do |x|
      unless x == 0
        power *= lmbda
        factorial *= x
      end
      value = (e_to_minus_lambda / factorial) * power
      # the following double inversion/conversion bounds the result
      # by the significant bits in the mantissa of a float
      approx = Rational(1, (1 / value).to_f)
      h[x] = approx
      break if x > lmbda && approx.numerator <= 1
    end
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  lmbda = (ARGV.shift || 2.0).to_f  # read in a lambda (defaults to 2.0)
  pmf = rational_poisson(lmbda)     # create the pmf for a Poisson with that lambda
  pmf.each { |key, value| puts "p(#{key}) = #{value} = #{value.to_f}" }
  puts "cumulative error = #{1.0 - pmf.values.inject(&:+)}"  # does it sum to 1?
end
```

Things to know as you glance through the code.  Appending `.to_r` to a value or expression converts it to a rational, i.e., a ratio of two integers; values with an `r` suffix are rational constants; and `(0...).each` is an open-ended iterator which will loop until the `break` condition is met.

That little script produces results such as:

```
localhost:pjs$ ruby poisson_rational.rb 1.0
p(0) = 2251799813685248/6121026514868073 = 0.36787944117144233
p(1) = 2251799813685248/6121026514868073 = 0.36787944117144233
p(2) = 1125899906842624/6121026514868073 = 0.18393972058572117
p(3) = 281474976710656/4590769886151055 = 0.061313240195240384
p(4) = 70368744177664/4590769886151055 = 0.015328310048810096
p(5) = 17592186044416/5738462357688819 = 0.003065662009762019
p(6) = 1099511627776/2151923384133307 = 0.0005109436682936699
p(7) = 274877906944/3765865922233287 = 7.299195261338141e-05
p(8) = 34359738368/3765865922233287 = 9.123994076672677e-06
p(9) = 67108864/66196861914257 = 1.0137771196302974e-06
p(10) = 33554432/330984309571285 = 1.0137771196302975e-07
p(11) = 33554432/3640827405284135 = 9.216155633002704e-09
p(12) = 4194304/5461241107926203 = 7.68012969416892e-10
p(13) = 524288/8874516800380079 = 5.907792072437631e-11
p(14) = 32768/7765202200332569 = 4.2198514803125934e-12
p(15) = 256/909984632851473 = 2.8132343202083955e-13
p(16) = 16/909984632851473 = 1.7582714501302472e-14
p(17) = 1/966858672404690 = 1.0342773236060278e-15
cumulative error = 0.0
```

Comment: very nice code , I appreciate you sharing. The `.to_r` is interesting, and I took special note of `approx = Rational(1, (1 / value).to_f)` . Lots to digest and experiment with, Its a fun and frustrating challenge to work in a language like solidity that is so limited, you can always try it out at http://remix.ethereum.org the Solidity IDE , when I get further I'll come back and share a link, thanks again @pjs